# How to chain multiple case expressions together in Scala

Tags: scala

I need to have a function of type: `Int => String`, which is like:

```scala
val h: Int => String = {
  case 1 => "one"
  case 2 => "two"
  case _ => "_"
}
```

For better modularity, I want to break it into sth. like this:

```scala
val handler1: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 1 => "one"
}

val handler2: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 2 => "two"
}

val handlerX: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case _ => "_"
}


val h: Int => String = {
  handler1.orElse(handler2).orElse(handlerX)
}
```

My question is:
1) How much is the difference (degradation) in the performance of `case-match`
2) Is there any better way for the same purpose? Or at least can we simplify the above version? It's tedious to repeat the same type declaration.

Comment: As far as I know, compiler is not able to optimize a lot such function composition, so it's quite predictable there will be performance degradation (simple patmat vs. Composition with multiple invocations)

Comment: The only real way to know if something affects your performance is to measure it. It may be slower, but it may not matter at all. Another option would be to have some **Map[String, Int]** and combine them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand how your second variant improves modularity, but okey, lets say it does...

Not to repeat the same type you can do like this

```
val handlers: List[PartialFunction[Int, String] ] = List(
  { case 1 => "one" },
  { case 2 => "two" },
  { case 3 => "three" },
  { case 4 => "four" },
  { case 5 => "five" },
  { case 6 => "six" },
  {case _ => "_"}
)

val h = handlers.foldLeft[PartialFunction[Int, String]](null)((agg, f) => {
  if (agg == null) f else agg.orElse(f)
})
```

the perfomance will be degraded, but even in 100 000 usages it will not be more than 50 mls...So it depends how much iterations this code will come through and what difference will be critical for you.

Comment: I would just use `reduce` here to avoid the `null`.

Comment: Or `def f(i: Int): String = { val it = handlers.iterator; def g: String = it.next().applyOrElse(i, (_: Int) => g); g }`.  I see `orElse` is really `applyOrElse`.